# Want to use multi-thread with powershell job to run separate windows form because show dialogue freeze parent form

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-forms-designer, showdialog, powershell-jobs

I tried to build an application with windows form with Powershell,

I encountered a problem,

When i run my parent form, i have no problem, i can open a child form but when my child form is open, i can't go back to my parent form, i search on internet and it's ShowDialogue fault but i really want to use both form in same time.

I tried to use powershell job and i ran my function (parent form) on a powershell job but nothing happenned,

My job is in background state but it exist when i do get-job,

It is possible to modify job specifity (change background status) so it's not invisible for me ?

Is there another way i can use two form's windows in same time and not stuck only on child form ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try `.Show()` instead of `ShowDialogue()`.

Comment: I tried but i can't interract with my buttons and my parent form is frozen